# Git Push code to 2 separate repositories at different times manually

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I need help in setting up a new project in GIT.

My Scenario is as follows:

1. I will have 2 separate servers with different repositories.
2. Consider them as Staging and Production.
3. I will have the original code on my local development machine.
4. After completing functionality the code should be first pushed to staging server and than to the Production server.
5. One scenario which will frequently appear is that I might not required to push all changes to Production.
6. Suppose I had pushed 6 changes today to Staging server than I might need to push only 2 changes to Production and the remaining changes on some another day.

Basically, first all commits go to staging server and only selected commits goes to Production server and that also may be on same or different days.

Is this possible?

If yes can you let me know how or using which tool can we achieve this if this not fully achievable using GIT.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

---

The first method is the **most** preferred method, and that is using `git remote`.

On your standard git repository, running `git remote -v` will usually show you the following:

```
origin  <url_to_git_repo> (fetch)
origin  <url_to_git_repo> (push)
```

You can add more by using `git remote add <name> <url>`.

In this case, you would `git remote add staging <staging_server_repo_location>`, and `git remote add prod <prod_server_repo_location>`.

When you want to push changes to your staging server, you would use `git push staging <branch_name>`.

Then, when pushing changes to your production server, you would use `git push prod <branch_name>`.

This method allows you to make full use of Git's branching system, as opposed to the second method, detailed below.

---

The second one is the **least** preferred method, and is achieved by using different branches.

For example, you would have your `master` branch, a `staging` branch, and a `production` branch.

You would split up your workflow across branches as you see fit.